# How to find the norm of this bounded linear operator?

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

$K(t,s)$ is measurable, $a\leq t$, $s \leq b$. $\int_a^b |K(t,s)| \, dt$ exists for almost every $s$, and it's essentially bounded about $s$. Let $y = T(x):y(t) = \int_a^b K(t,s)x(s) \, ds$. Then $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $L[a,b]$ to $L[a,b]$, and the norm of $T$ is $\operatorname*{esssup}\limits_{(a\leq s\leq b)}\int_a^b |K(t,s)|\,dt$

I know the norm of $T\leq \operatorname{esssup}\dots$, but I don't know how to prove the '$=$'.

Comment: i can see the result if $K\ge0.$

Comment: You are right, but I still don't know how to deal with general situation. My friend tried to use the delta function but later I realized δ(x) didn't belong to L[a,b].And still no idea now 

Comment: Um.. What about integrating $\int_a^b |K(t,s)x(s)|ds$ (let's call it g(t)) on set A and B respectively, where g is positive on A and negative on B, since it's annoying to deal with the symbol '|•|'. And let x(s) be the product of the characteristics function of set C={s|$\int_a^b |K(t,s)|dt$>esssup-ε} and the number (m(C))^(-1). It seems work.